# gender related activism scale

Tags: social-psychology, measurement, gender

I'm looking for a self-report measure that assesses involvement and interest in activism that centers around gender equity, including (but not limited to) topics like gender equality, segregation and inclusion, and body politics (such as reproductive rights and trans health rights).

I intend to use this measure with a sample of high schoolers as part of a self-report survey. However, I'm interested in learning about self-report scales that have been validated for adults too.

The [Activism Orientation Scale (AOS) (Corning & Myers, 2002)](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Eacorning/Activism%20Orientation%20Scale.pdf) is one example, except this is geared towards adults, and does not specifically focus on gender politics. I need a scale that can be used with high school age students.

Comment: I feel this question is a little unclear. You are looking to assess *"involvement and interest in activism that centers around gender equity"* based on what criteria?  Surely full assessment would need to look at their social media profiles, communications with lobby groups etc? How extensive an assessment are you looking for?  What examples have you found so far?

Comment: I am editing my comment to clarify I'm looking for a Survey measure (self-report)